# Android viewBinding usage

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I have a question about viewBinding in Android. Usually, I use it like this

```
lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
setContentView(binding.root)
```

But I also saw that someone uses it like this

```
private val binding: ActivityMainBinding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) 

setContentView(binding.root)
```

Is there any difference? What is the better way?

Comment: this is wrong way  
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes we encounter a scenario where we want to avoid initializations of some fields in a class till they are actually needed. A classic example could be, the case of heavy singletons. That is when you use **lazy**.

Normally, properties declared as having a non-null type must be initialized in the constructor. However, fairly often this is not convenient. For example, properties can be initialized through dependency injection, or in the setup method of a unit test. In this case, you cannot supply a non-null initializer in the constructor, but you still want to avoid null checks when referencing the property inside the body of a class.

To handle this case, you can mark the property with the **lateinit** modifier

The upper scenario is the one which is used because the binding is initialized in a lifecycle method later.

In case of lazy it would be called when it is need in the code ie: setContentView which is again inside a lifecycle method ..

Use any one and stick to it

Answer (score 2):

1. Fragments

I would not recommend using any of these if you are in a Fragment, as you are welcoming the memory leaks this way.
Inside of the `onDestroyView()` (if Fragment) you have to nullify your ViewBinding instance by doing

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    binding = null
}
```

If you are using lazy or `lateinit` it won't allow you to do that, as `lateinit` forces you to have non-nullable values, and lazy forces you to have immutable variable.

The best approach is to use it as described in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments)

**TLDR;**

```
private var _binding: DialogStartcodeBinding? = null
private val binding get() = requireNotNull(_binding)

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = MyViewBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

 override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```

2. Activity

Inside of the Activity, I would go either as with Fragment and nullify ViewBinding inside of the `onDestroy()` or with any of the version you described. But FYI in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities) the `lateinit` approach is being used.

**TLDR;**
Use whichever option makes you happier :) Both are fine in the `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there are differences between lateinit and lazy

**lateinit** -> Only **var** can be used with this and only Non Nullable values allowed

**Lazy** -> the object will be created only when it is called, otherwise there will be no object creation. Only **val** is allowed in lazy